# ListView onItemClick which implements Activity is not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview extends Activity and use custom adapter because I want icon and text on the listview.

```
String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.menu_title);
    TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.menu_icon);
    ImageAndTextAdapter iadapter = new ImageAndTextAdapter(ctx, R.layout.row, options, icons);
    MenuList.setAdapter(iadapter);
```

Then I use the setOnItemClickListener to make the listview clickable but fail.

```
MenuList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Revision.class);    
            Menu.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
    });
```

Here is the logcat:

> 11-22 16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-22 16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   cs.ucl.cw.Menu$1.onItemClick(Menu.java:54) 11-22 16:55:17.419:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   11-22 16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
>   11-22 16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 11-22 16:55:17.419:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 11-22 16:55:17.419:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
>   11-22 16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 11-22
>   16:55:17.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

AIM:
clickable listview which would bring up other activities. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your problem might actually be in Revision.class.  Without seeing that code, i cant say for sure, but the part of the Logcat that points to that would be:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw that line but wasn't aware of it because the graphic layout tab in eclipse display it perfectly with no error.